# Uncaught ReferenceError. Prototype function is not found inside jQuery event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting the following error when I press the submit button:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addText is not defined
```

- How come the 'click' handling function can not find the class prototype function 'addText'?
- What can I do to fix this?
- If this a bad way of handling events? (I come from a java background, and I'm a little unsure of the best practices with object oriented javascript)

Here is the code:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        //Class ctor
        function MyClass() {
            this.msg = "Hello World!";
        }
        //This method appends text to the given doc element
        MyClass.prototype.addText = function(doc) {
            $(doc).append('<br/>'+this.msg);
        };
       /*
        * This method adds a 'click' listener to the given element which 
        * calls the 'addText' method on its parent.
        */
        MyClass.prototype.listenToButton = function(btn) {
            $(btn).bind({
                click: function(event) {
                    addText($(this).parent());
                }
            });
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {
            //Create instance of class
            var c = new MyClass();
            //Listen to button
            c.listenToButton($("#mybutton"));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Button: <input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Submit"></div>
</body>
```

Obviously I am using jQuery. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here's what I've learned:

- The 'click' handling function can not find the function 'addText' because 'this' no longer references the class instance but the sender of the event.
- To work around this, I should save the current 'this' scope in a variable outside the handler function.
- I'm not sure if handling events this way is bad practice or not, but it works so I'm going with it.
- Also, I should use 'on' instead of 'bind' since it seems like 'bind' calls 'on' anyways.

Thanks everyone for your quick replies!

Comment: You should be using `on` instead of `bind`. And you need to learn about scope of `this`.

Comment: Basically, inside the click event, the context ( `this` ) is no longer the instance of MyClass, it's the element that was *clicked*, therefore addText is not defined.

Comment: @epascarello ok, what is the difference?

Comment: @Kevin B So Javascript anonymous functions are unlike Java anonymous functions where Javascript's can't find a function outside of the current nested level?

Comment: @SoulDZIN No, it can, just not with the way you defined it. Typically when you're calling a method of the instance, you want to include the instance when calling it rather than just assuming it's immediately available, such as the way vher2 did it.

Comment: @SoulDZIN, read the docs, it tells you right on the bind() page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyClass.prototype.listenToButton = function(btn) {
        var that = this;
        $(btn).bind({
            click: function(event) {
                that.addText($(this).parent());
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank's for the prompt reply! Is this how these situations should be handled or is this a symptom of bad design?

Comment: @SoulDZIN This is a typical solution to the problem, another option is to pass `this` into the function using an iife, or to control what the context is with `Function.bind` or `jQuery.proxy`. Defining a `that` var is the normal way of handling it though.